# OM Components vs plain functions

Tags: clojurescript, om

I am going through this [OM tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial) but it's not clear to me when to use OM components vs plain functions (in particular the om/component macro).

The tutorial writes:

> The first argument is a function that takes the application state data
>   and the backing React component, here called owner. This function must
>   return an Om component - i.e. a model of the om/IRender interface,
>   like om.core/component macro generates

```
; here the function (fn [app owner]) indeed returns an OM component
(om/root
  (fn [app owner]
    (om/component (dom/h2 nil (:text app))))
  app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})
```

In the next section we find the following example of a rendering loop for a list:

```
 ; this one does not return an om component (or does it?). it returns a virtual dom
(om/root
  (fn [app owner]
    (apply dom/ul nil
      (map (fn [text] (dom/li nil text)) (:list app))))
  app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app0"))})
```

Here, we're basically just returning a (virtual) dom directly, not wrapped in an OM component, so the question would be: Why does the om/component macro exist? The macro simply helps us to reify the IRender function, but it appears that we can also just use plain functions for that. I would reify OM components that have lifecycle state (or need the owner to call get-props) but for components that just need to create virtual dom I'd rather go for simple functions (so I don't need the build/build-all functions to create my virtual dom). What am I missing here? Why is the macro still useful (and I don't see it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same question last week, and I dug through the Om source code to find out.

**I couldn't find any functional difference between using the `om/component` macro and not.**  But maybe this info can shed some light on someone who knows more about React.

Any function `f` passed to `om/root` (and subsequently `om/build`) is placed inside of a container Om component.  This Om component is just a dummy React component that forwards all life-cycle events to the result of `f` if it implements Om's lifecycle protocols (i.e. when it is a reify object).

If the result of `f` is not a reify object that implements those protocols, it is assumed to be a React component, and it is used as the value returned by the `render` lifecycle function.

(relevant: [Om's render function here](https://github.com/swannodette/om/blob/master/src/om/core.cljs#L301-L319))

Comment: Okay, then I get it. So the macro might be there when you want to wrap a plain react component into an OM component. Maybe future versions of OM will have slighly different semantics in the om/component macro, so you better use the macro even all you have to do is to return a react component.

Answer (score 3):

The om/component macro is just a shorthand for the defn and reify combination when you do not need to pass in state

Comment: That's part of the story. From the docs, "Sugar over reify for quickly putting together components that _only  need to implement_ om.core/IRender and don't need access to the owner argument."